# query posts in wordpress

Tags: theme-development, wp-query, loop, query-posts

I want to filter my query results just before the_loop starts in word press. I only want the results having term_id or term_taxonomy_id equal to 1.

```
query_posts('post_type=my_post&term_id=1&posts_per_page=6');
```

This is returning all rows, I am new to word press so I am not sure that we can use term_id in query_posts. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Please simply don't use `query_posts()`. Read more about the _why_ here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Answer (score 1):

There is no `term_id` parameter. [You need a `tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'yourtaxname',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 1
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Notice that I've use `new WP_Query` and not [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). Don't use `query_posts`.

Doing the above will create a new query. That is, it will request information from the data in addition to any information that has already been requested. That is fine, if that is what is what you need but if possible, it is better to alter the main query before any posts are retrieved. This reduces the load on the server which should translate into a quicker load time for the site.

To interrupt the main query use `pre_get_posts`. This would be the equivalent code for doing that.

```
function restrict_tax_wpse_100006($qry) {
  if (is_page('somepage_id_title_or_slug')) {
    $qry->set('post_type','my_post');
    $qry->set('posts_per_page',6);
    $qry->set('tax_query', 
        array( 
             array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'yourtaxname',
                  'field' => 'id',
                  'terms' => 1 // or array(1)
             ) 
        )
    );
  }
}
```