# Displaying posts based on category

Tags: php, categories, functions

I recently got some help here on getting a few posts to display in block format. I was wondering if someone could assist me with modifying the code to limit the posts that show up either by category or by tag. I've listed the code below:

```
<div id="mini_stream">
    <ul>
<? $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 4
);

$loop = new wp_Query($args);

while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'category-thumb');
    the_title( '<h6>', '</h6>' );
    echo '</a>';
endwhile;

wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It sounds like you need something like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100016/21376 If that doesn't work, explain why. How is your case different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `category_name or cat` in your `arguments` (args) array.

```
<div id="mini_stream">
    <ul>
<? $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'category_name'=>'html',
);

$loop = new wp_Query($args);

while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'category-thumb');
    the_title( '<h6>', '</h6>' );
    echo '</a>';
endwhile;

wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need to call `wp_reset_query()` in this case. This code will also generate incorrect HTML output (you don't output `<li>` anywhere in it, so this list won't be correct HTML).

Answer (score 1):

**For tags you can use**:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'tag' => 'cooking'
    );
    ... REST OF YOUR CODE
```

Other parameters you can use for tags are:

- `tag` (string) - use tag slug.
- `tag_id` (int) - use tag id.
- `tag__and` (array) - use tag ids.
- `tag__in` (array) - use tag ids.
- `tag__not_in` (array) - use tag ids.
- `tag_slug__and` (array) - use tag slugs.
- `tag_slug__in` (array) - use tag slugs.

**For categories you can use**:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'category_name' => 'cooking'
    );
    ... REST OF YOUR CODE
```

And other parameters you can use for categories are:

- `cat` (int) - use category id.
- `category_name` (string) - use category slug (NOT name).
- `category__and` (array) - use category id.
- `category__in` (array) - use category id.
- `category__not_in` (array) - use category id.

Links to Codex (have you even tried to search?):

1. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters
2. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters

Comment: My searches ended up mostly coming up with using query_posts, this works, thanks!